# ios - UITapGestureRecognizer with UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a scrollable, non-ediable UITextView. I want to add a gesture recognizer to it so when double tap it, a tool bar will show, double tap it again, tool bar will hide.

I have disabled the selection function of the text view by subclassing it and override `canBecomeFirstResponder` to return NO.

It seems ok when i just simply add the tap recognizer to it.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showOrHideToolbars)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[textView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

It works good, excepts if i tap and hold on the text view, after that, the recognizer will not receive any action any more.

This means, if I tap and hold on the text view (i guess text view goes into a selection mode even i disable the selection function), no more double tap can be detected now.

I tried to use single tap then problem is gone but i do need to use double tap.

I also tried to override touch event handler methods, but no use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of other gesture recognizers attached to a text view. Since you don't seem to need them. You can remove them.

```
textView.gestureRecognizers = nil;
```

before adding your double tap recognizer. It works.

Comment: Thanks!! It actually also disable the scroll function, so instead of remove all recognizers, I still have keep the pan recognizer.

Comment: Forgot about that. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks... I managed it via Deepdak's suggestion... The following code will do the required thing :)

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *taprecog = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openFolderController)];
taprecog.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
taprecog.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[textView gestureRecognizers]];
for (int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++) {
    if ([[arr objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class] ]) {
        [arr removeObject:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
    }   
}

[textView addGestureRecognizer:taprecog];
[taprecog release];
```

Comment: are you missing [textView setGestureRecognizers:arr]?

Comment: You do realize that you're just making a copy of the gesture recognizer array & manipulating that? The text view's array is never affected here.

Comment: Actually this whole loop is pointless. Just create an empty array & set that.

Comment: @BradGoss, no, I aint missing setGestureRecognizer, if you see wisely I am using addGestureRecognizer which adds the new tap gesture.

Comment: @MachOSX, I have implemented this in one of my problems and it works fine. Have you tried it ?